# Faithful representation of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a nontrivial $p$-group. Let $H$ be the intersection of the center of $G$ and the set of elements in $G$ of exponent $p$. Let $\rho: G\rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation. Show that if $\rho|_H$ is faithful, then $\rho$ is faithful.

A concrete example is the $2$-dimensional irreducible representation of $Q_8$. Somehow, if the $\rho$ on $i,j,k$ is not faithful, then $\rho$ on ${1,-1}$ is not faithful. So I think I may need to divide the group into layers according to exponents. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: It is not true that $H$ is cyclic of order $p$. For example $G$ could be $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The representation is not necesarily irreducible, as far as you have told us. My group $G$ certainly has faithful representations!

Comment: why should $H$ be a group?

Comment: I am sorry that I made a mistake in the argument. I really need $V$ be irreducible. Otherwise, $\rho(h)$ just commutes with elements in the image, but not with the whole matrix ring. It is not necessarily in the center of the matrix ring, and hence not necessarily a scalar.

Comment: If $\rho$ maps $i$ to the identity, for example, then it is also maps $i^2=-1$ to the identity!

Comment: @vnd, $H$ is the subset of elements of order $p$ in the center $Z(G)$ of $G$, and, in fact, in every abelian group $A$ the set of elements of order $p$ is subgroup.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez that is if you consider the identity itself to be of order $p$.

Comment: Well, I assumed correctly that you were able to fill that detail up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rho$ is not faithful, then its kernel is a normal subgroup of $G$. Now in a $p$-group, every normal subgroup intersects non-trivially the center $Z(G)$ and, moreover, as that intersection is a $p$-group, the intersection contains an element of order $p$. This means that $\ker\rho$ intersects your subgroup $H$ and, therefore, that $\rho|_H$ is not faithful.